# I have only the last row when I select the database slqlite android

Tags: android, arrays, sqlite, arraylist

I have been trying to get all rows from the sqlite database. But I got only last row from the following codes.

```
DBController dbController = new DBController(this);
    SQLiteDatabase database = dbController.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor fila = database.rawQuery("select diaCaptura from LecturasBD", null);
    ArrayList<String> lista = new ArrayList();
    String name = "";
    if(fila.moveToFirst()){
        while(fila.isAfterLast() == false){
            name = fila.getString(fila.getColumnIndex("diaCaptura"));
            lista.add(name);
            fila.moveToNext();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

A much less confusing (and cleaner) approach to looping through the `Cursor` would be to use a `while` loop with `moveToNext();`

```
DBController dbController = new DBController(this);
SQLiteDatabase database = dbController.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor fila = database.rawQuery("select diaCaptura from LecturasBD", null);
ArrayList<String> lista = new ArrayList();
String name = "";

while(fila.moveToNext()){
    name = fila.getString(fila.getColumnIndex("diaCaptura"));
    lista.add(name);
}

fila.close(); // don't forget to close your cursor
```

Answer (score 0):

Try "moveToNext" (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html) as "isAfterLast" is merely true when the cursor is at the very end (also see link above).